slate and scrollable text
I'm working on adding a slate to Unity using the Mixed Reality Toolbox and incorporating scrollable text, but I'm encountering issues. Despite my efforts, I can't seem to position the text on the slate and make it scrollable. Can someone assist me with this?

which version of MRTK are you working with?

i am working with MRTK 2

You can use ScrollingObjectColloection to implement this. For more details, please refer to Scrolling object collection — MRTK2.
